# How to specify which of two cloudfront distributions to use?

Tags: javascript, python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm setting up a Django app using S3 for storage. I would like to use a streaming cloudfront distribution for videos, and a download distribution for images.

Is there a way to specify which distribution I'd like to use to host a particular file? I'll be uploading the files directly from the browser to S3 using the method described here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434.

Comment: Create a new StorageBackend specific to your cloudfront. Specify which storage backend to use for a given field... `images = models.ImageField(storage=CloudFrontStorage1)`

Comment: When I said directly from the browser I meant from the browser to S3 - I've updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do that. For serving images through "download" cloudfront distribution and video through "streaming" distribution, you can have just have one cloudfront streaming distribution. It will work just fine. You will have to work with CORS for directly uploading files from browser. Also, for streaming video to some flash player (flowplayer etc) , you might require crossdomain.xml and if you are doing private streaming define Origin-access-identity while creating "streaming" cloudfront distribution.